# KendoUI Grid Look and Feel different in demo

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I copied all the htmls and css in demo, except kendo.all.min.js, since I'm only trying out the opensource version.

However, the look and feel is different. I checked the code on the demo and I am doing the same thing. Any ideas?

DEMO
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-popup.html

MINE
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAzxR.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the font-size of your page. The Kendo UI demos have the following CSS rule:

```
html {
   font: 75% Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```